# How to securely send basic auth headers without exposing in the source code

Tags: javascript, java, angular, basic-authentication

I am in a scenario where backend API is protected with Basic auth, from angular 5 I am passing the basic auth details in the headers like below.

```
    let name: string = "XXXXXXX";
    let pass: string = "XXXXXX";
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers =  headers.append('Authorization',  'Basic'+ btoa(name + ":" + pass));
    headers =  headers.append('X-XSRF-TOKEN', 'XXXXXXXXXX');
    headers =  headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    return this.httpClient.get<any>('http://xxx.xxx', { headers : headers});
```

after I do the ng build --prod, I still can see the credentials in the source code. Is there a safe way to do this without showingoff the credentials.

Comment: Nope there isnt.

Comment: I would think you would want to have the user validate their credentials when first visiting the site, once authenticated, send the user an access token, then pass this when making any requests. This token would then allow the user to call a server side method which in turn would call out to the API and return the result. Thus, hiding the credentials from client side viewing.

Comment: can you please tell what is the ideal approach to avoid this situation @JonasW.

Comment: It is usually not a password but a token you pass in the header